# easygui.msgbox ('You entered ' + flavour) TypeError: must be str, not NoneType

Tags: python-3.6, easygui

```
import easygui

flavour = easygui.enterbox('What is your favourite ice cream flavour?')

easygui.msgbox ('You entered ' + flavour)
```

What do I do here so that when I hit the 'cancel' button on the 'enter' box it doesn't return an error? At the moment I get the following error:
"easygui.msgbox ('You entered ' + flavour)
TypeError: must be str, not NoneType"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is that `msgbox` wants the message to be string. However, if you hit cancel, `flavour` is a `NoneType` object. You can add an if statement to make sure your code does not error out if you hit cancel. Do something like:

```
flavour = easygui.enterbox('What is your favourite ice cream flavour?')

if flavour is not None:
    easygui.msgbox ('You entered ' + str(flavour))
else:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

this will do it

```
import easygui
while True:
flavour = easygui.enterbox('What is your favourite ice cream flavour?(type quit to quit)')
a = bool(flavour)
if a == False:
    easygui.msgbox('you did not enter something')
elif a == True:
    if flavour == 'quit':
        break
    else:
        easygui.msgbox ('You entered ' + flavour)
```

(i can make the program better but bigger and larger)