# "TypeError: must be str, not NoneType" error when calling string in Python function

Tags: python-3.x, string, function, typeerror, nonetype

Here is a function to write job status to a process log in MySQL:

```
# job status function        
def mysql_write_jobstatus(host, user, password, batch_id, source, status,
                          job_start_dt, job_finish_dt = None, filename = None, error = None):
    if job_finish_dt is None:
        status_sql = "INSERT INTO schema.table (\
        batch_id, run_date, source, status, data_processed, job_start_dt)\
        values ('" + batch_id + "', '" + rundate + "', '" + source + "', '" + status + "', '" + data_processed + \
                "', '" + job_start_dt + "');"
    else:
        status_sql = "UPDATE schema.table SET status = '" + status + "', \
        job_finish_dt = '" + job_finish_dt + "', filename = '" + filename + "', error = '" + error + "' WHERE batch_id = '" + batch_id + "' AND \
        source = '" + source + "';"
    try:
        con = pymysql.connect(host=lol,
                                user=lol,
                                password=lol,
                                autocommit=True,
                                local_infile=1)
        print('Connected to DB: {}'.format(host))
        # Create cursor and execute Load SQL
        cursor = con.cursor()
        cursor.execute(status_sql)
        con.close()
        
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error: {}'.format(str(e)))
        sys.exit(1)
```

I am getting the error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-222-0d62a2bb45ad>", line 75, in mysql_write_jobstatus
    source = '" + source +"';"

TypeError: must be str, not NoneType
```

**source** is a string variable that is only defined once at the top of the code like so:

```
source = 'workstuff'
```

Everything I see leads me to believe it's a string.  The other called variables in the same SQL call work just as expected.

I have removed all variables from my global environment.

Any ideas?

[easygui.msgbox ('You entered ' + flavour) TypeError: must be str, not NoneType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42919803/easygui-msgbox-you-entered-flavour-typeerror-must-be-str-not-nonetype) is not helping because **source** is a manually defined string, and should never change to a NoneType.

Comment: From what I understand: Your `source` variable is a function parameter, are you sure you're passing a correct value in? It's not enough to declare `source = "text"` outside of function scope. Also, you might want to use an "f-string", it's hard to read your query.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?  This sounds like its on the right track.  Where and how should i define source?

Comment: How exactly are you calling your function? It should looks something like: `mysql_write_jobstatus(host=your_host, user=your_user ...and so on, source=your_source .. and so on) ` Where `your_host` etc. are variables you define somewhere in your code. You have to "pass in" those variables you declared right here `def mysql_write_jobstatus(host, user, password, batch_id, source, status, job_start_dt, job_finish_dt = None, filename = None, error = None):`

Comment: I cannot call it yet because the else statement throws the error.

status_sql = "UPDATE schema.table SET status = '" + status + "', \
        job_finish_dt = '" + job_finish_dt + "', filename = '" + filename + "', error = '" + error + "' WHERE batch_id = '" + batch_id + "' AND \
        source = '" + source + "';"

Comment: but yes that is how i'm calling it, and all the variables are defined before calling it, including source.

Comment: What kind of an error is it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232006/discussion-between-zabada-and-notsirius-a).

Comment: what happens if you print(source ) as the first thing in that method?

Comment: it prints the string 'workstuff'.  the error only occurs after the AND in the second STATUS_SQL variable.